# Return number of working days between 2 dates minus weekend and bank holidays

Tags: t-sql

Hi i am trying to script a TSQL function that will return the number of working days between 2 dates minus weekend days and UK public holidays, here is what i have so far (due to lack of experience there may be syntax errors etc, appreciate any corrections):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_WorkDays (@StartDate AS DATETIME, @EndDate AS DATETIME)

--Define the output data type.
RETURNS INT
AS
--Calculate the RETURN of the function.
BEGIN
     RETURN (SELECT
        (DATEDIFF(dd,@StartDate, @EndDate)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk,@StartDate, @EndDate)*2)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        )END
GO
```

Now i have access to a table (or i can copy it if need be) that stored the UK bank holidays here is a screeny of setup:

[image: Sceeny of table setup]

im fairly new to TSQL and i am struggling with a way to look through the list of bankhols and remove them from the returning INT of the function and therefore return the correct number of working days between the 2 dates passed to the function.

any help and advice would be greatly appreciated (especially if its written in an easy to understand form ;)  )

Comment: "i have not checked the code for errors as of yet" - so don't post it yet!

Comment: i have edited what i meant by that comment for the sakes of comments like yours Mitch, but hey we all start somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a Calendar table for things like this - one entry for every date, and metadata like weekdays, weekends and holidays for various contexts. It is very handy for a lot of tasks. (You can set it up with a simple `WHILE` loop.)

The counting may look like this:
(`calendarWeekday` would be filled with `DATEPART(Weekday...` upon generation, results vary with region).

```
SELECT COUNT(calendarDate)
FROM tblCalendar
WHERE 
    calendarDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate
    AND calendarWeekday NOT IN (1, 7) AND calendarIsBankHoliday = 0
```

Comment: This was useful, however i have started a new question as i have to work with the resources i have already and i have made some progress which i guess the next question addresses better.